# How to send a broadcast packet to a specific MAC address

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below code to send a Broadcast packet to test my network. The code work but the Dst mac address is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff. How can I change the Dst Mac address to a specific mac address?

````
import socket
import time

SERVER_ADDRESS = "localhost"
SERVER_PORT = 10000
 
# create a socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)  #socket.SO_BROADCAST
server.settimeout(0.2)
address = (SERVER_ADDRESS,SERVER_PORT)
print(f"server {SERVER_ADDRESS} at port {SERVER_PORT}")
server.bind(("",60550))
message = b"This is AJ Testing Broadcast on the network using Python................"
while True:
    # broadcast
    server.sendto(message, ('255.255.255.255', 60551))
    print("message sent!")
    time.sleep(2)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to open raw socket and not a normal `UDP` socket. RAW sockets give you control to the whole data packets that get sent. to open a raw socket use

```
import socket
import sys
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
except socket.error:
    print('Socket could not be created. Error Code')
    sys.exit()

# build your packet and send it as normal using socket.send() method.
```

note that to open raw sockets you must have root access so run your command with `sudo`. Also note that this way you have full access to the data packets that get sent to the air so you must be familiar with format of data structure of [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) frames that will carry the payload(your data). as a side note you have to disable your network card checksumming as a precaution using `sudo ethtool -K eth1 tx off` in case you use wired connection.